# Shopware6: Update shippingMethods after completion of the purchase process

Tags: shopware6

Shopware Version: 6.4.20.2

Shopware allows you to specify different shipping methods. If the user selects a shipping method during the purchase process, this method will also be preselected for future orders.

In my store, I would like to adjust this behavior so that the default shipping method is used again after the purchase process has been completed.

To achieve this, I have created an EventSubscriber.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Revier\Checkout\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


class CheckoutSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'frontend.checkout.finish.page.response' => 'onCheckoutFinishPageIsGenerated',
        ];
    }

    public function onCheckoutFinishPageIsGenerated($event)
    {
        // set shippingMethod to default
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, despite my research, I haven't got any further.
I have already tried the following:

- Asking AI Copilot: https://developer.shopware.com/chat.html
- Searching the official git repository to find out which event needs to be intercepted
- Ersellen eines SubscripteEvents: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-subscribed-event-in-shopware6/